# Staggered view with UICollectionReusableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I am using UICollectionReusableView for header and CollectionviewCell for display cell. I want to set staggered view in collectionview cell.

I have tried with layout custom but at that time UICollectionReusableView is automatically deleted. (Set collectionview layout property layout to custom instead of flow)

Can you please give me way how to achieve above functionality.

(UICollectionReusableView view contain more two collectionview)